# IOS calling Google Places with coordinates I provide

Tags: ios, google-places-api, cllocation

I'm implementing google places api on IOS.  I'd like call google place client using latitude and longitude coordinates that I provide, instead of tuning on location manager and blindly calling placesClient (IOS). My goal here is to be able to apply a filter to the coordinates prior to calling for a google place to be sure the coordinates are accurate.

Can this be done?

thanks in advance!
Mike

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Get a single place (which is only an estimate), display a list of places for a user to pick from? Are you looking for an actual place, or an address?

Comment: HI Jcaron, Im trying to call googlePlaces with a set of coordinates... like findGooglePlace( myCLLocation )

Comment: I'm looking for an actual place based on coordinates (lat,long) that I supply. thanks!